# Unexpected second mutable borrow on a struct

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust, so forgive if this is duplicate of other questions. I have looked up other questions but they are all slightly different, and I feel I do not know enough about rust to know if their problem is similar to mine.

I have created a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bb3a9eff3fe1fd15a2bdc02b6b35dfff) of my code replicating my problem - code pasted in below.

The error that I get is `cannot borrow '*context' as mutable more than once at a time`, but the way I read it, the first `&mut` is released before the second one. Can someone shed light on why this is happening?

```rust
struct Context {
    foo: Option<String>,
    bar: Option<String>
}

impl Context {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Context {
            foo: None,
            bar: None
        }
    }

    fn foo(&mut self) -> &String {
        if self.foo.is_none() {
            let message = String::from("foo");
            self.foo = Some(message);
        }

        self.foo.as_ref().unwrap()
    }

    fn bar(&mut self) -> &String {
        if self.bar.is_none() {
            let message = String::from("bar");
            self.bar = Some(message);
        }

        self.bar.as_ref().unwrap()
    }
}

fn print(context: &mut Context) {
    let foo = context.foo();
    let bar = context.bar();

    println!("{}{}", foo, bar);
}

fn main() {
    let mut context = Context::new();

    print(&mut context);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption that the first `&mut` is released before the second one is incorrect.

The function: `fn foo(&mut self) -> &String` has the lifetimes elided, so more fully is `fn foo<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a String`, so the lifetime of the `&mut` is that of the returned `String` which is assigned to `foo`.

Since the lifetime of `foo` will be until the `println!` macro, the `&mut` reference will have the same lifetime, preventing it from being borrowed by the second reference.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, there is no way to get round this. I cannot define a set of lifetimes that will make this work?

Comment: Correct (I think) - here are some more detailed discussions of the issue. https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/relaxing-the-borrow-checker-for-fn-mut-self-t/3256/20